# How to fix "the octet sequence #(130) cannot be decoded." in pgloader

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, pgloader

I'm trying to migrate a database from sqlite to postgresql using [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/).
My sqlite db is data.db, so i try this

```
pgloader ./var/data.db postgres://***@ec2-54-83-50-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb?sslmode=require
```

Output:

```
pgloader version 3.6.1
sb-impl::*default-external-format* :UTF-8
tmpdir: #P"/var/folders/65/x6spw10s4jgd3qkhdq96bk8c0000gn/T/"
KABOOM!

2019-04-11T19:22:47.022000+01:00 NOTICE Starting pgloader, log system is ready.

FATAL error: :UTF-8 stream decoding error on #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/dev/www/Beyti/var/data.db" {1005892A93}>: the octet sequence #(130) cannot be decoded.

Date/time: 2019-04-11-18:22An unhandled error condition has been signalled: :UTF-8 stream decoding error on #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/dev/www/Beyti/var/data.db" {1005892A93}>: the octet sequence #(130) cannot be decoded.
```

An idea about this problem? thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue.

The culprit "octet sequence #(130)" corresponded to "é" in my case, which was encoded as \x82.
iconv failed.
I replaced in the byte stream those corrupted \x82 with \x65 (ascii char "e"), and I got out of it.

```
<bad_file xxd -c1 -p | sed s/82/65/ | xxd -r -p > good_new_file
```

(cheers to Natacha on irc freenode #gcu :) )
Edit : French issues? same problem with #133 "à", same solution \x85 -> \x61

Edit 2 : A little generalization I just found :
The "octet sequence" pgloader refers to, is the decimal ranking of the [ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/). When you get higher than 127 in the "octet sequence", you step in the extended ascii table and generate errors.
I just got an issue with #144? It is \x90. replace :)